# Why does slice assignment only work in-place for my function's list parameter if I slice it before?

Tags: python, in-place

For a python course that I am taking, we were assigned to reverse a list of provided strings using an in-place algorithm. While this can be done by directly swapping indexes, I saw that way did not account for adding more strings to the list and would require additional coding if that happened.

My first shot at the solution looked like:

```
words = ['this' , 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'reverse', 'me']
def function_1(a_list):
    a_list = a_list[::-1]
    print(a_list) #Used this to show it is indeed reversed inside of the function
    return a_list

function_1(words)
print(words)
```

When this is run, the list is reversed when called inside of the function but not outside of the function.

I wanted to see if I could make it actually impact the provided list outside of the function, and I ultimately got:

```
words = ['this' , 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'reverse', 'me']
def function_2(a_list):
    a_list[:] = a_list[::-1] 
    print(a_list) #Used this to show it is indeed reversed inside of the function
    return a_list

function_2(words)
print(words)
```

With the second function, the string (words) is actually changed and I considered my in-place algorithm assignment completed. But why does it only happen in the second function? Is it really in-place or is more happening that what appears to be happening?

Comment: `function_2` isn't an in-place algorithm either - it modifies the original list, but it does so by creating a reversed list and then copying that second list's data into the first list. An in-place algorithm isn't allowed to use that much scratch space.

Comment: `a_list[::-1]` give a new list in reverse order. `a_list = a_list[::-1]` let the variable refer to the new list. The old list is unchanged. while `a_list[:]  = a_list[::-1]` replace the old list contents with the new list ones.

Comment: (People often say that something "operates in-place" if it modifies the input, but an in-place algorithm has stricter requirements.)

Comment: `return`ing anything from a function is *utterly pointless* if you do not assign (or otherwise use) the result of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an assignment inside the method, `a_list` now points to a list in a new location that exists only in the scope of the method. Once you make an assignment to the name `a_list` inside the method, you are now editing a variable that does not exist outside the method, and have essentially lost access to the original `a_list`: any future references to `a_list` in the method will not be to the parameter that got passed in.

So you should make an assignment that indexes into the original array in memory, which is what you have done. This will persist because you are assigning values directly in the original variable.

Comment: It's not a new local variable - it's the same local variable the passed-in list was bound to. The problem isn't that you're using a new variable; the problem is that all you did was rebind the variable instead of modifying the original list.